# Make package install on terminal - error

Tags: ios, macos, ssh, terminal, jailbreak

I have developed a tweak, in which to finally finish my work, I have to use THEOS to build, compile, and install the files onto my iDevice. This is what happens:

```
Jordans-MacBook-Pro:CustomColr jordan$ make package install
Making all for tweak CustomColr...
make[2]: Nothing to be done for internal-library-compile.
Making stage for tweak CustomColr...
dpkg-deb: building package com.jordanmckee.customcolr in ./com.jordanmckee.customcolr_0.0.1-13_iphoneos-arm.deb.
install.exec "cat > /tmp/_theos_install.deb; dpkg -i /tmp/_theos_install.deb && rm /tmp/_theos_install.deb" < "./com.jordanmckee.customcolr_0.0.1-13_iphoneos-arm.deb"
```

Ok, it's going well... until I get this:

```
ssh: connect to host 10.196.58.6 port 22: Operation timed out
make: *** [internal-install] Error 255
```

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the text of the messages, instead of linking to third-party sites.

Comment: There, I've edited it.

Comment: Are you able to SSH into the device just using the `ssh` command? Do you have the OpenSSH package installed on the device?

Comment: I just installed the OpenSSH client onto my MacBook. I'll try and use the ssh command.

Comment: You need OpenSSH installed on the iOS device. THEOS uses SSH to copy and install the package onto the device. Possibly the operation is timing out because there is no SSH sever running on the device to respond to the connection.